# Identifying input values for which a function does NOT generate a specific output

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I built a data structure in form of a function that outputs certain strings in response to certain input strings like this:

```
type mydict = String -> String

emptydict :: mydict
emptydict _ = "not found"
```

Now I can add entries into this dictionary by doing the following:

```
addentry :: String -> String -> mydict -> mydict
addentry s1 s2 d s 
| s1 == s = s2
| otherwise = d s
```

To look for s2's I can simply enter s1 and look in my dictionary

```
 looky :: String -> mydict -> String
 looky s1 d = d s1  --gives s2
```

My goal is now to create another function `patternmatch` in which I can check which s1's are associated with an s2 that starts with a certain pattern. Now the pattern matching itself isn't the problem, but I am not sure how can I keep track of the entries I entered, i.e. for which input is the output not `"not found"` ?

My idea was to try to keep track of all the s1's I entered in the `addentry` function and add them to a separate list. In `patternmatch` I would feed the list elements to `looky`, such that I can get back the associated s2's and check whether they match the pattern.

So my questions:

1) Is this list building approach good or is there a better way of identifying the inputs for which a function is defined as something other than `"not found"`?

2) If it is the right approach, how would I keep track of the s1's? I was thinking something like:

```
addentry s1 s2 d s
| last (save s1) == s = s2
| otherwise = d s1
```

And then `save s1` being a function generating the list with all s1's. `last (save s1)` would then return the most recent `s1`. Would appreciate any help on implementing `save s1` or other directions going from here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Once you have completed your pedagogical exercise, you might like to look into [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html), or [`TMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/total-map-0.0.6/docs/Data-TotalMap.html) for a more advanced usage that abolishes the distinction between "don't have that `String`" and "have that `String` but it maps to `"not found"`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is hard-coded such that the only criteria for finding a key is by presenting the same exact key. What you need is a more flexible approach that lets you provide a criteria other than equality. I took the liberty of making your code more general and using more conventional names for the functions:

```
import Prelude hiding (lookup)

-- instead of k -> Maybe v, we represent the dictionary as
-- (k -> Bool) -> Maybe v where k -> Bool is the criteria
-- on which to match the key. by using Maybe v we can signal
-- that no qualifying key was found by returning Nothing
-- instead of "not found"
newtype Dict k v = Dict ((k -> Bool) -> Maybe v)

empty :: Dict k v
empty = Dict $ const Nothing

-- insert a new key/value pair
insert :: k -> v -> Dict k v -> Dict k v
insert k v d = Dict $ \f -> if f k then Just v else lookupBy f d

-- lookup using the given criteria
lookupBy :: (k -> Bool) -> Dict k v -> Maybe v
lookupBy f (Dict d) = d f

-- lookup using the default criteria (equality with some given key)
lookup :: Eq k => k -> Dict k v -> Maybe v
lookup k = lookupBy (k==)

-- your criteria
startsWith :: String -> String -> Bool
startsWith s = undefined -- TODO

lookupByPrefix :: String -> Dict String v -> Maybe v
lookupByPrefix = lookupBy . startsWith
```

I should mention that while this is a great exercise for functional programming practice and general brain-expansion, it's a terrible way to implement a map. A list of pairs is equivalent and easier to understand.

As a side note, we can easily define an instance of `Functor` for this type:

```
instance Functor (Dict k) where
  fmap f d = Dict $ \g -> fmap f (lookupBy g d)
```

Comment: `singleton` seems like a weird primitive to use here. Why not instead define `empty = Dict $ const Nothing`, and then call `insert` on that? That avoids the duplication between `insert` and `singleton`.

Comment: Nice! I would also be tempted to use `Dict ((k -> Bool) -> [v])` since many keys satisfy a predicate, in general. This makes it possible to recover the support set as `someDict (const True)`. (Of course, in the long run inserting/deleting a key will still lead to a slower and slower dictionary -- a real Map would still be better)

Comment: @chi That's quite clever. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader ;)